# How to work with reverse tunneling in Objective-C SSH2?

Tags: objective-c

I have some sample SSH2 code and I was able to create the tunneling and I can forward the ports from localhost to a remote server.
But i need to know about reverse port forwarding. Is it possible in SSH2?

Port Forwarding:

> listener = libssh2_channel_forward_listen_ex([server session],
>   remote_listenhost, remote_wantport, remote_listenport, 1);

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a [jailbreaked ios device can install putty](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OP-3u6J5EN0), at which point, the world is your oyster.